# If everything has color, can we describe an object in frequency?

Tags: optics, visible-light, frequency

If color we see is the reflected color, is everything every frequency and we are like the tuning knob on a radio, electrons oscillating accordingly?

An excerpt from The Little Book of String Theory by Steven Scott Gubser

"To appreciate the wavelike characteristics of light, imagine an electron who decides to go sunbathing in a laser beam. A laser beam is a steady, coherent, intense beam of light. Here’s the key point: When the electron steps into the laser beam, it pulls him first to one side, then the other, back and forth at some frequency. That frequency is the one that enters into the equation E = hv . Visible light has a frequency somewhat less than 10^15 oscillations per second. This analogy is fanciful, but it’s easy to give a much more practical example. Radio waves are really the same thing as light, just with a much smaller frequency. FM radio waves have a frequency of about 10^8 oscillations per second, or 10 8 Hz. One of the most popular stations where I live is New Jersey 101.5, which broadcasts at 101.5 megahertz. One megahertz is a million hertz, or 10 6 Hz. So 100 megahertz is 10 8 Hz. Thus 101.5 megahertz is just a smidgen over 10 8 oscillations per second. An FM radio is constructed so that electrons inside it can oscillate at just about this frequency. When you tune a radio, what you are adjusting is the frequency at which the electrons inside its circuitry prefer to oscillate. Much like our sunbathing electron, the electrons inside the radio soak up the radio waves washing over the radio."

This led me to believe that everything (referencing TOE) is weaved on a fabric of frequency. In this format, excitation of particles is what makes them tangible.

I use the word tangible because, though I've forgotten where I read this,

"The frequency of light really means something tangible. It’s the frequency that you tune a radio to receive. So when an electron jumps from one energy level to another, emitting a single photon in the process, you can use the frequency of the photon to judge unambiguously what the energy difference is between the two levels."

This thought process led me to focus on absorption and reflection

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! This question is somewhat vague, making it difficult to understand what you are asking. You can edit your question to make it more clear what your question is; the community really appreciates the contribution!

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Sorry, I'm still really confused. I'll leave it up in case it interests someone. Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. While I'd love to read minds, I'm stuck with words for communication, and the words above are difficult to interpret. What do you mean by "is everything every frequency"? By "we" do you mean collective we (all of humanity), more collective we (everything composed of matter, that is to say, every "thing" in existence), or some other definition? The knob on a radio controls electronic filtering in ways that are determined by whether you're talking about AM or FM radio, not to even broach the subject of satellite. Why are electrons oscillating? What do you mean?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist I've edited my question. Hopefully, this shows that I'm trying to learn how to communicate with the physics community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is everything every frequency

Kind of. The reflected light contains *some* amount of every frequency in the visible spectrum, but it will contain different amounts of different frequencies; we call the distribution of intensity among the different frequencies the *reflection spectrum* of the object.

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://www.sarracenia.com/astronomy/remotesensing/physics050.html)</sup>

Our eyes' color vision works by seeing how much the spectrum of the light overlaps with the sensitivity curves of the Red, Green and Blue cone cells in our retina. This behaviour is indeed quite similar to how a (reasonably broad-band) antenna can pick out the intensity that lies in some pre-defined range of frequencies and output a single number for that.

For more details, see e.g. [the Wikipedia article on color vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision).